# How to cut off an old swing to get rid of it

Tags: metal-cutting

I need to dispose of an old swing in my yard. Problem is some screws are so rusty they can't be unscrewed and the whole swing wont's pass the door.

Is there any simple way to cut this thing into a few pieces ? I guess the rods are hollow so perhaps it's not too hard. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Caution: Once you acquire a reciprocating saw, everything looks like a rusty bolt that needs to be cut off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have numerous options:

- Drill out the screws with a drill bit larger than the screw diameter.
- Use a hand hack saw to cut it into manageable pieces.
- Use a reciprocating saw - a "Sawzall" to cut it into manageable pieces.
- Beat it into submission with a sledge hammer until it folds and bends and breaks (get medieval on it!)

My recommendation would be the sawzall with a new 10" demolition blade. You can probably have it cut into pieces in 10 minutes that way with little sweat.

If you don't own a recipricating saw, you can rent one at your local tool rental place or big box hardware store (Lowes, Menards, Home Depot, etc)

*edit:* Like SteveR says...make sure to wear your safety gear!

Comment: Thanks DaveNay for the pieces of advice and thanks the others  too

Answer (score 2):

You can get a metal cutting abrasive wheel to fit your circular saw. Just be careful, it will cut like butter through the pipes. I would also recommend wearing safety glasses, gloves.

Answer (score 1):

I simply folded mine in on itself bending the tubes, but you could just use a hacksaw,angle grinder or reciprocating saw to cut the tubes up or to cut the rusted screws.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the right tools, then almost anything is possible. Without the right tools, it takes elbow grease, if it is even possible.

So I'd use my reciprocating saw, with a metal cutting blade in it. Lacking that, I might pull out an angle grinder, or an air powered cutoff tool. You need not even cut the pieces completely through. Just cut it most of the way, and then bend it a few times to fatigue the stub of metal that remains. It will break then easily.

Lacking any of that, now I'd be left with a hacksaw, and elbow grease. Use a good blade and it will cut faster.

You can either cut the tubing into pieces, or cut away the screws that hold it together. Sometimes one or the other is easier. And sometimes disposal companies don't like to take long sections. (Ours won't take anything longer than a few feet.)

No matter what you do, wear good strong gloves, as old rusty pieces of metal will be hard on hands that are not accustomed to such work. Safety glasses are a good thing too, as pieces of flying rusty metal are not good for your eyes.

Lacking even that, I'd have no choice but to pay someone else to take it away, or let it rust away in place. A hundred years from now, and it will be mostly gone on its own.

Note that if you can easily enough bring the steel to a salvage yard, you may even salvage a few dollars from the scrap.